# org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.BackendException: Backend Internal error: Exception during IR lowering

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have the below code, and it compiles errors per title.

```
class MyComposable(newTextValue: String) {
    var myComposable = @Composable {
        Text(newTextValue)
    }
}
```

More error as below

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.BackendException: Backend Internal error: Exception during IR lowering
File being compiled: /app/src/main/java/com/example/learnabstractcomposeview/MyComposableFun.kt
The root cause java.lang.RuntimeException was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generate(FunctionCodegen.kt:50)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.CodegenUtil.reportBackendException(CodegenUtil.kt:239)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.CodegenUtil.reportBackendException$default(CodegenUtil.kt:235)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PerformByIrFilePhase.invokeSequential(performByIrFile.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PerformByIrFilePhase.invoke(performByIrFile.kt:55)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PerformByIrFilePhase.invoke(performByIrFile.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompositePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:29)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompositePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:29)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompilerPhaseKt.invokeToplevel(CompilerPhase.kt:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.doGenerateFilesInternal(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:195)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.generateModule(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:60)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.compileCorrectFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.generate(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:331)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:123)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:58)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:170)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:434)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:120)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:357)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally$default(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:299)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:159)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:80)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:622)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:100)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1713)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor107.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while generating code for:
FUN CLASS_STATIC_INITIALIZER name:<clinit> visibility:public/*package*/ modality:FINAL <> () returnType:kotlin.Unit
  BLOCK_BODY
    SET_FIELD 'FIELD FIELD_FOR_OBJECT_INSTANCE name:INSTANCE type:com.example.learnabstractcomposeview.ComposableSingletons$MyComposableFunKt visibility:public [final,static]' type=kotlin.Unit origin=INITIALIZE_FIELD
      value: CONSTRUCTOR_CALL 'public constructor <init> () [primary] declared in com.example.learnabstractcomposeview.ComposableSingletons$MyComposableFunKt' type=com.example.learnabstractcomposeview.ComposableSingletons$MyComposableFunKt origin=null
    SET_FIELD 'FIELD name:lambda-1 type:kotlin.Function2<androidx.compose.runtime.Composer, kotlin.Int, kotlin.Unit> visibility:internal [static]' type=kotlin.Unit origin=INITIALIZE_FIELD
      value: CALL 'public final fun composableLambdaInstance (key: kotlin.Int, tracked: kotlin.Boolean, block: kotlin.Any): androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambda declared in androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaKt' type=androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambda origin=null
        key: CONST Int type=kotlin.Int value=-985533843
        tracked: CONST Boolean type=kotlin.Boolean value=false
        block: BLOCK type=com.example.learnabstractcomposeview.ComposableSingletons$MyComposableFunKt.<clinit>.<no name provided> origin=null
          CLASS LAMBDA_IMPL CLASS name:<no name provided> modality:FINAL visibility:public/*package*/ superTypes:[kotlin.jvm.internal.Lambda; kotlin.jvm.functions.Function2<androidx.compose.runtime.Composer, kotlin.Int, kotlin.Unit>]
            $this: VALUE_PARAMETER INSTANCE_RECEIVER name:<this> type:com.example.learnabstractcomposeview.ComposableSingletons$MyComposableFunKt.<clinit>.<no name provided>
            CONSTRUCTOR GENERATED_MEMBER_IN_CALLABLE_REFERENCE visibility:public/*package*/ <> ($newTextValue:kotlin.String) returnType:com.example.learnabstractcomposeview.ComposableSingletons$MyComposableFunKt.<clinit>.<no name provided> [primary]
              VALUE_PARAMETER BOUND_VALUE_PARAMETER name:$newTextValue index:0 type:kotlin.String
              BLOCK_BODY
                SET_FIELD 'FIELD FIELD_FOR_CAPTURED_VALUE name:$newTextValue type:kotlin.String visibility:public/*package*/ [final]' type=kotlin.Unit origin=INITIALIZER_OF_FIELD_FOR_CAPTURED_VALUE
                  receiver: GET_VAR '<this>: com.example.learnabstractcomposeview.ComposableSingletons$MyComposableFunKt.<clinit>.<no name provided> declared in com.example.learnabstractcomposeview.ComposableSingletons$MyComposableFunKt.<clinit>.<no name provided>' type=com.example.learnabstractcomposeview.ComposableSingletons$MyComposableFunKt.<clinit>.<no name provided> origin=null
                  value: GET_VAR '$newTextValue: kotlin.String declared in com.example.learnabstractcomposeview.ComposableSingletons$MyComposableFunKt.<clinit>.<no name provided>.<init>' type=kotlin.String origin=null
                DELEGATING_CONSTRUCTOR_CALL 'public constructor <init> (arity: kotlin.Int) declared in kotlin.jvm.internal.Lambda'
                  arity: CONST Int type=kotlin.Int value=2
                BLOCK type=kotlin.Unit origin=null
            FUN name:invoke visibility:public modality:FINAL <> ($this:com.example.learnabstractcomposeview.ComposableSingletons$MyComposableFunKt.<clinit>.<no name provided>, $composer:androidx.compose.runtime.Composer?, $changed:kotlin.Int) returnType:kotlin.Unit
              annotations:
                Composable
              overridden:
                public abstract fun invoke (p1: P1 of kotlin.jvm.functions.Function2, p2: P2 of kotlin.jvm.functions.Function2): R of kotlin.jvm.functions.Function2 declared in kotlin.jvm.functions.Function2
              $this: VALUE_PARAMETER INSTANCE_RECEIVER name:<this> type:com.example.learnabstractcomposeview.ComposableSingletons$MyComposableFunKt.<clinit>.<no name provided>
              VALUE_PARAMETER name:$composer index:0 type:androidx.compose.runtime.Composer? [assignable]
              VALUE_PARAMETER name:$changed index:1 type:kotlin.Int
              BLOCK_BODY
                CALL 'public final fun sourceInformation (composer: androidx.compose.runtime.Composer, sourceInformation: kotlin.String): kotlin.Unit declared in androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerKt' type=kotlin.Unit origin=null
                  composer: GET_VAR '$composer: androidx.compose.runtime.Composer? [assignable] declared in com.example.learnabstractcomposeview.ComposableSingletons$MyComposableFunKt.<clinit>.<no name provided>.invoke' type=androidx.compose.runtime.Composer? origin=null
                  sourceInformation: CONST String type=kotlin.String value="C38@1125L18:MyComposableFun.kt#22949u"
                WHEN type=kotlin.Unit origin=IF
                  BRANCH
                    if: CALL 'public final fun OROR (arg0: kotlin.Boolean, arg1: kotlin.Boolean): kotlin.Boolean declared in kotlin.internal.ir' type=kotlin.Boolean origin=null
                      arg0: CALL 'public final fun not (): kotlin.Boolean [operator] declared in kotlin.Boolean' type=kotlin.Boolean origin=null
                        $this: CALL 'public final fun EQEQEQ (arg0: kotlin.Any?, arg1: kotlin.Any?): kotlin.Boolean declared in kotlin.internal.ir' type=kotlin.Boolean origin=null
                          arg0: CALL 'public final fun xor (other: kotlin.Int): kotlin.Int [infix] declared in kotlin.Int' type=kotlin.Int origin=null
                            $this: CALL 'public final fun and (other: kotlin.Int): kotlin.Int [infix] declared in kotlin.Int' type=kotlin.Int origin=null
                              $this: GET_VAR '$changed: kotlin.Int declared in com.example.learnabstractcomposeview.ComposableSingletons$MyComposableFunKt.<clinit>.<no name provided>.invoke' type=kotlin.Int origin=null
                              other: CONST Int type=kotlin.Int value=11
                            other: CONST Int type=kotlin.Int value=2
                          arg1: CONST Int type=kotlin.Int value=0
                      arg1: CALL 'public final fun not (): kotlin.Boolean [operator] declared in kotlin.Boolean' type=kotlin.Boolean origin=null
                        $this: CALL 'public abstract fun <get-skipping> (): kotlin.Boolean declared in androidx.compose.runtime.Composer' type=kotlin.Boolean origin=null
                          $this: GET_VAR '$composer: androidx.compose.runtime.Composer? [assignable] declared in com.example.learnabstractcomposeview.ComposableSingletons$MyComposableFunKt.<clinit>.<no name provided>.invoke' type=androidx.compose.runtime.Composer? origin=null
                    then: BLOCK type=kotlin.Unit origin=null
                      CALL 'public final fun Text-fLXpl1I (text: kotlin.String, modifier: androidx.compose.ui.Modifier?, color: androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color, fontSize: androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit, fontStyle: androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontStyle?, fontWeight: androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight?, fontFamily: androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily?, letterSpacing: androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit, textDecoration: androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextDecoration?, textAlign: androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign?, lineHeight: androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit, overflow: androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextOverflow, softWrap: kotlin.Boolean, maxLines: kotlin.Int, onTextLayout: kotlin.Function1<androidx.compose.ui.text.TextLayoutResult, kotlin.Unit>?, style: androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle?, $composer: androidx.compose.runtime.Composer?, $changed: kotlin.Int, $changed1: kotlin.Int, $default: kotlin.Int): kotlin.Unit declared in androidx.compose.material.TextKt' type=kotlin.Unit origin=null
                        text: GET_FIELD 'FIELD FIELD_FOR_CAPTURED_VALUE name:$newTextValue type:kotlin.String visibility:public/*package*/ [final]' type=kotlin.String origin=null
                          receiver: GET_VAR '<this>: com.example.learnabstractcomposeview.ComposableSingletons$MyComposableFunKt.<clinit>.<no name provided> declared in com.example.learnabstractcomposeview.ComposableSingletons$MyComposableFunKt.<clinit>.<no name provided>.invoke' type=com.example.learnabstractcomposeview.ComposableSingletons$MyComposableFunKt.<clinit>.<no name provided> origin=null
                        modifier: COMPOSITE type=kotlin.Nothing? origin=DEFAULT_VALUE
                          CONST Null type=kotlin.Nothing? value=null
                        color: COMPOSITE type=androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color origin=DEFAULT_VALUE
                          CALL 'public final fun <unsafe-coerce> <T, R> (v: T of kotlin.jvm.internal.<unsafe-coerce>): R of kotlin.jvm.internal.<unsafe-coerce> declared in kotlin.jvm.internal' type=androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color origin=null
                            <T>: kotlin.Long
                            <R>: androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
                            v: CONST Long type=kotlin.Long value=0
                        fontSize: COMPOSITE type=androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit origin=DEFAULT_VALUE
                          CALL 'public final fun <unsafe-coerce> <T, R> (v: T of kotlin.jvm.internal.<unsafe-coerce>): R of kotlin.jvm.internal.<unsafe-coerce> declared in kotlin.jvm.internal' type=androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit origin=null
                            <T>: kotlin.Long
                            <R>: androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit
                            v: CONST Long type=kotlin.Long value=0
                        fontStyle: COMPOSITE type=kotlin.Nothing? origin=DEFAULT_VALUE
                          CONST Null type=kotlin.Nothing? value=null
                        fontWeight: COMPOSITE type=kotlin.Nothing? origin=DEFAULT_VALUE
                          CONST Null type=kotlin.Nothing? value=null
                        fontFamily: COMPOSITE type=kotlin.Nothing? origin=DEFAULT_VALUE
                          CONST Null type=kotlin.Nothing? value=null
                        letterSpacing: COMPOSITE type=androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit origin=DEFAULT_VALUE
                          CALL 'public final fun <unsafe-coerce> <T, R> (v: T of kotlin.jvm.internal.<unsafe-coerce>): R of kotlin.jvm.internal.<unsafe-coerce> declared in kotlin.jvm.internal' type=androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit origin=null
                            <T>: kotlin.Long
                            <R>: androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit
                            v: CONST Long type=kotlin.Long value=0
                        textDecoration: COMPOSITE type=kotlin.Nothing? origin=DEFAULT_VALUE
                          CONST Null type=kotlin.Nothing? value=null
                        textAlign: COMPOSITE type=kotlin.Nothing? origin=DEFAULT_VALUE
                          CONST Null type=kotlin.Nothing? value=null
                        lineHeight: COMPOSITE type=androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit origin=DEFAULT_VALUE
                          CALL 'public final fun <unsafe-coerce> <T, R> (v: T of kotlin.jvm.internal.<unsafe-coerce>): R of kotlin.jvm.internal.<unsafe-coerce> declared in kotlin.jvm.internal' type=androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit origin=null
                            <T>: kotlin.Long
                            <R>: androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit
                            v: CONST Long type=kotlin.Long value=0
                        overflow: COMPOSITE type=androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextOverflow origin=DEFAULT_VALUE
                          CALL 'public final fun <unsafe-coerce> <T, R> (v: T of kotlin.jvm.internal.<unsafe-coerce>): R of kotlin.jvm.internal.<unsafe-coerce> declared in kotlin.jvm.internal' type=androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextOverflow origin=null
                            <T>: kotlin.Int
                            <R>: androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextOverflow
                            v: CONST Int type=kotlin.Int value=0
                        softWrap: COMPOSITE type=kotlin.Boolean origin=DEFAULT_VALUE
                          CONST Boolean type=kotlin.Boolean value=false
                        maxLines: COMPOSITE type=kotlin.Int origin=DEFAULT_VALUE
                          CONST Int type=kotlin.Int value=0
                        onTextLayout: COMPOSITE type=kotlin.Nothing? origin=DEFAULT_VALUE
                          CONST Null type=kotlin.Nothing? value=null
                        style: COMPOSITE type=kotlin.Nothing? origin=DEFAULT_VALUE
                          CONST Null type=kotlin.Nothing? value=null
                        $composer: GET_VAR '$composer: androidx.compose.runtime.Composer? [assignable] declared in com.example.learnabstractcomposeview.ComposableSingletons$MyComposableFunKt.<clinit>.<no name provided>.invoke' type=androidx.compose.runtime.Composer? origin=null
                        $changed: CONST Int type=kotlin.Int value=0
                        $changed1: CONST Int type=kotlin.Int value=0
                        $default: CONST Int type=kotlin.Int value=65534
                  BRANCH
                    if: CONST Boolean type=kotlin.Boolean value=true
                    then: CALL 'public abstract fun skipToGroupEnd (): kotlin.Unit declared in androidx.compose.runtime.Composer' type=kotlin.Unit origin=null
                      $this: GET_VAR '$composer: androidx.compose.runtime.Composer? [assignable] declared in com.example.learnabstractcomposeview.ComposableSingletons$MyComposableFunKt.<clinit>.<no name provided>.invoke' type=androidx.compose.runtime.Composer? origin=null
            FIELD FIELD_FOR_CAPTURED_VALUE name:$newTextValue type:kotlin.String visibility:public/*package*/ [final]
            FUN BRIDGE name:invoke visibility:public modality:OPEN <> ($this:com.example.learnabstractcomposeview.ComposableSingletons$MyComposableFunKt.<clinit>.<no name provided>, p1:kotlin.Any?, p2:kotlin.Any?) returnType:kotlin.Any?
              $this: VALUE_PARAMETER INSTANCE_RECEIVER name:<this> type:com.example.learnabstractcomposeview.ComposableSingletons$MyComposableFunKt.<clinit>.<no name provided>
              VALUE_PARAMETER BRIDGE name:p1 index:0 type:kotlin.Any?
              VALUE_PARAMETER BRIDGE name:p2 index:1 type:kotlin.Any?
              EXPRESSION_BODY
                CALL 'public final fun invoke ($composer: androidx.compose.runtime.Composer?, $changed: kotlin.Int): kotlin.Unit declared in com.example.learnabstractcomposeview.ComposableSingletons$MyComposableFunKt.<clinit>.<no name provided>' type=kotlin.Unit origin=BRIDGE_DELEGATION
                  $this: GET_VAR '<this>: com.example.learnabstractcomposeview.ComposableSingletons$MyComposableFunKt.<clinit>.<no name provided> declared in com.example.learnabstractcomposeview.ComposableSingletons$MyComposableFunKt.<clinit>.<no name provided>.invoke' type=com.example.learnabstractcomposeview.ComposableSingletons$MyComposableFunKt.<clinit>.<no name provided> origin=null
                  $composer: TYPE_OP type=androidx.compose.runtime.Composer origin=IMPLICIT_CAST typeOperand=androidx.compose.runtime.Composer
                    GET_VAR 'p1: kotlin.Any? declared in com.example.learnabstractcomposeview.ComposableSingletons$MyComposableFunKt.<clinit>.<no name provided>.invoke' type=kotlin.Any? origin=null
                  $changed: TYPE_OP type=kotlin.Int origin=IMPLICIT_CAST typeOperand=kotlin.Int
                    GET_VAR 'p2: kotlin.Any? declared in com.example.learnabstractcomposeview.ComposableSingletons$MyComposableFunKt.<clinit>.<no name provided>.invoke' type=kotlin.Any? origin=null
          CONSTRUCTOR_CALL 'public/*package*/ constructor <init> ($newTextValue: kotlin.String) [primary] declared in com.example.learnabstractcomposeview.ComposableSingletons$MyComposableFunKt.<clinit>.<no name provided>' type=com.example.learnabstractcomposeview.ComposableSingletons$MyComposableFunKt.<clinit>.<no name provided> origin=null
            $newTextValue: GET_VAR 'newTextValue: kotlin.String declared in com.example.learnabstractcomposeview.MyComposable.<init>' type=kotlin.String origin=null

    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generate(FunctionCodegen.kt:50)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generate$default(FunctionCodegen.kt:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ClassCodegen.generateMethodNode(ClassCodegen.kt:360)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ClassCodegen.generateMethod(ClassCodegen.kt:377)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ClassCodegen.generate(ClassCodegen.kt:135)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmLowerKt$codegenPhase$1$1.lower(JvmLower.kt:304)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.FileLoweringPhaseAdapter.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:120)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.FileLoweringPhaseAdapter.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:116)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PerformByIrFilePhase.invokeSequential(performByIrFile.kt:65)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No mapping for symbol: VALUE_PARAMETER name:newTextValue index:0 type:kotlin.String
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.IrFrameMap.typeOf(irCodegenUtils.kt:64)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitGetValue(ExpressionCodegen.kt:641)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitGetValue(ExpressionCodegen.kt:131)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrGetValueImpl.accept(IrGetValueImpl.kt:29)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.gen(ExpressionCodegen.kt:211)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.generateConstructorArguments(ExpressionCodegen.kt:615)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitConstructorCall(ExpressionCodegen.kt:603)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitConstructorCall(ExpressionCodegen.kt:131)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrConstructorCallImpl.accept(IrConstructorCallImpl.kt:28)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitStatementContainer(ExpressionCodegen.kt:433)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitContainerExpression(ExpressionCodegen.kt:446)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitContainerExpression(ExpressionCodegen.kt:131)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitor$DefaultImpls.visitBlock(IrElementVisitor.kt:60)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitBlock(ExpressionCodegen.kt:379)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitBlock(ExpressionCodegen.kt:131)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrBlockImpl.accept(IrBlockImpl.kt:48)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.gen(ExpressionCodegen.kt:211)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.IrCallGenerator$DefaultImpls.genValueAndPut(IrCallGenerator.kt:49)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.IrCallGenerator$DefaultCallGenerator.genValueAndPut(IrCallGenerator.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitCall(ExpressionCodegen.kt:486)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitCall(ExpressionCodegen.kt:131)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrCallImpl.accept(IrCallImpl.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitFieldAccess(ExpressionCodegen.kt:714)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitFieldAccess(ExpressionCodegen.kt:131)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitor$DefaultImpls.visitSetField(IrElementVisitor.kt:73)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitSetField(ExpressionCodegen.kt:744)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitSetField(ExpressionCodegen.kt:131)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrSetFieldImpl.accept(IrSetFieldImpl.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitStatementContainer(ExpressionCodegen.kt:433)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitBlockBody(ExpressionCodegen.kt:437)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitBlockBody(ExpressionCodegen.kt:131)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrBlockBody.accept(IrBody.kt:54)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.generate(ExpressionCodegen.kt:228)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.FunctionCodegen.doGenerate(FunctionCodegen.kt:122)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generate(FunctionCodegen.kt:48)
    ... 53 more
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was due to **gradle caches**.
you can make a simple change in the file that causes the error and rebuild. I may give an error to another file next.
You can clear all build caches too.

Comment: I keep hitting this and having to do clean/rebuild. Any idea what is causing the issue and how to prevent it from happening regularly?

Comment: @0101100101 is your compose version up to date? I haven't gotten this error for a while.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, I just need to add a `val` or `var` to it

```
class MyComposable(val newTextValue: String) {
    var myComposable = @Composable {
        Text(newTextValue)
    }
}
```